# Host key verification problem with gitlab CI

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci, ssh-keys

Running a gitlab CI pipeline I'm trying to easy-deploy the repository's code on a EC2 instance.

I generated my ssh-keys for gitlab in my PC to clone and push my code. Then I moved the public and private keys also in the ec2. This just o allow to make the *git clone "git.repo.git"* in the ec2 instance.

I think this should be the problem, but I can't find a solution, I get this error

Cloning into 'repo-name'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

This is my gitlb ci file: (really easy, just for tests)

```
stages:        
  - deploy

deploy-job:      
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - cat $SSH_KEY > cred.pem && chmod 400 cred.pem
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i cred.pem ubuntu@id-amazon.com git clone git@gitlab.com:repo/test.git
```

Is there a way to pass these credentials correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using your keys to connect to `id-amazon.com`, user `ubuntu`.

But they would not be used by the git clone executed on that server, which would explain why the clone fails.

Although it fails first because the `gitlab.com` fingerprint is not found in `~ubuntu/.ssh/knwon_hosts`.

See "[Using SSH keys with GitLab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.cn/14.0/ee/ci/ssh_keys/index.html)" and its [example SSH project](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/ssh-private-key/).
Double-check the result of `ssh-keyscan gitlab.com` with [GitLab SSH known_hosts entries](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/#ssh-host-keys-fingerprints).

---

As explained by the [OP Alex Sander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15248438/alex-sander) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74330546/host-key-verification-problem-with-gitlab-ci/74332373?noredirect=1#comment131288622_74332373)

> I think a mix of permissions problems, if the folder with the `.ssh` for the aws-key has 'too much permissions' I saw that it gives problems (I read that is because the ssh key has to be not 'viewable', inside the ubuntu folder I created another folder with chmod 777 in which I which I cloned the directory.
>
> And for the `.ssh` files all he permissions in the aws docs.
> To solve these problems I changed in a strange way the commands ran in the GitLab job but it was just this permission problem I think.

Comment: `    - apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client git -y
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts ` 

I added all this part as in the example project, with the new private key in ec2 host. Unfortunately I'm getting the same issue: **git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.** I did also ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

Comment: Can you try a ssh -Tv gitlab.com to check your key is actually used?

Comment: I changed the authentication method I'm using an access token to simplify things, git clone https://oauth2:$ACCESS_TOKEN@gitlab.com/repo/$CI_PROJECT_NAME.git /home/ubuntu/projects, now it has a bizarre behavior, it logs that is cloning regularly but no folder is created up to now. The folder in which it clones has chmod 777 to avoid problems now but it is still not creating anything.  The same command in the ec2 shell runs correctly so I think is a problem of the ssh -i command.

Comment: @alexsander A oauth2:token means HTTPS URL, so this is no longer related to SSH. Try a ls -alrth before and after the git clone, to check what you see.

Comment: yes I changed method because it seemed easier, using your suggestion I saw that the directory has been clonds but I can't see it using the ec2 shell, running 'whoami' in the gitlab pipeline it showed that the user is root and also the cloned repo is written by root by  ls -alrth . The strange thing  is that the root user in the ec2 can't see  these files. Moreover the usual commands that I run with ubuntu user like aws s3 from the aws cli are not avaiable maybe it depends by the type of shell used from the ssh -i command.

Comment: I think the root that clones the directory should be the root of the gitlab ci shell (?) that's why I can't see files in the ec2 shell and run aws

Comment: @alexsander The gitlab-ci shell is on a GitLab VM,  *from which* you are connecting to `id-amazon.com`. It (the GitLab-ci shell) does not see the remote machine content (`id-amazon.com`)

Comment: I solved the problem was s tupid issue running commands using ssh thank for help, I vote your answer, it solved ssh key problems

Comment: @alexsander Great! What was your other issue with running ssh commands?

Comment: I think a mix of permissions problems, if the folder with the .ssh for the aws-key has 'too much permissions' I saw that it gives problems (I read that is because the ssh key has to be not 'viewable', inside the ubuntu folder I created another folder with chmod 777 in which I which i cloned the directory. And for the .ssh files all he permissions in the aws docs. thanks again fo the help. To solve these problems I changed in a strange way the commands runned in the gitlab job but it was just this permission problem I think. That's because the bizarre behaviors.

Comment: @alexsander Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.